# SpringBoot With Empty H2 Database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, h2

So im trying to create table using h2 and spring boot but database always shows up empty
i think it's not reading my schema.sql file , im also using intellij idea IDE is there any configurations that i must fix in the IDE?here is my schema.sql file and application.properties file down below and a screenshot for the empty database:

**schema.sql**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Currencies;
CREATE TABLE Currencies (Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,Currency_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,);
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
server.port=9000
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.crewmeister</groupId>
    <artifactId>cm-coding-challenge</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cm-coding-challenge</name>
    <description>The java coding challenge for developer candidates applying at Crewmeister</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**h2 empty database screenshot:**
[image: h2_empty_database]

Comment: You have a syntax error in the `schema.sql`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` to let Spring create tables based on your entities. But keep in mind that the created tables will be destroyed and re-created each time the application is restarted, so take care to fill the tables with data Also, you can use flyway migration to manually specify table creation.

[about flyway](https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway)

[about ddl auto](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)